# Sender Email address of the New User Registration Email in DNN 7.2

Tags: email, dotnetnuke

First, I changed the admin email address with my email address for testing purpose. Then later I changed back to the original. But the problem is, now the new user registration email comes from my email address to admin email address. I am confused as to how dnn is taking my email address as the sender email address. Can anybody point out how the sender email address is configured in dnn in this case?

I have searched through various dnn community sites. But I haven't found an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your account is linked as the Administrator acount of the portal.
Go to `Admin > Site Settings`.

On that page select the tab `Advanced Settings`. There you will find the `Security Settings`. Change the Administrator account there. THat account will be the sender of the portal mails.